# Is there a way to skip the intro screens in Rocksmith 2014 for PC?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

Every time I start Rocksmith 2014, I have to sit through about 15 seconds' worth of intro screens.  Is there a way to skip all of that and get straight into the game?

Answer (score 5):

The Intro screen is there for a reason, the game is still in the process of loading:

> The game is actually still loading while the splash screens appear, so they're not actually increasing load -> play time, just giving you something different to look at while you wait for it to load.

Meaning the 15 Second wait is **not** removable and is **compulsory** to the game.

**BUT** Even if you did follow ***lh8registration*** method you would still have to wait that "15 Second" time for the game to load. (I do not know if this method works)

Reference: [Ubisoft](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/825853-Skipping-the-introduction-screens-Forums)

Comment: I came across that in my searches, but didn't put much stock in it.  First, the splash screens are timed too perfectly and happen to end just as the main guitar riff plays at the main menu.  The interval of each individual screen is just too constant to be based on actual load time.  Second, Rocksmith is installed on a conventional drive and I hear absolutely no disk access during this time, nor do I see my hard disk light flashing.

Comment: Just installed the game, loading time for me was 5 seconds.

Rig Spec's

CPU: Intel Xeon Processor E5-4610 v2 (16M Cache, 2.30 GHz) 

HDD: 1TB Samsung 840 EVO Series SATA-III 6.0Gb/s SSD *2

HDD2: 1TB Samsung 840 EVO Series SATA-III 6.0Gb/s SSD *2

MEMORY: 64GB (8GBx8) DDR3/2133MHz Quad Channel Memory

MOTHERBOARD: ASUS Sabertooth X79 ATX w/ TUF Armor

VIDEO: NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN Black Edition 6GB GDDR5 PCIe 3.0 x16 super clocked

VIDEO2: NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN Black Edition 6GB GDDR5 PCIe 3.0 x16 Super clocked

Answer (score 3):

From [this page](https://www.guideoui.com/rocksmith-2014-edition-remastered-how-to-skip-intros/) and [this page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1641309509).

Get rid of those annoying splash screens when the game boots up, and use your time getting better on your instrument instead!

Steps:

1. Download the modified cache.psarc from the link below.
2. Navigate to your ‘\steamapps\common\Rocksmith2014’ folder
3. Replace the ‘cache.psarc’ in your Rocksmith2014 folder with the modified one.

Have fun, and get quicker to work with your instrument and Rocksmith 2014!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zm_6RQcAju2vnOYSyju-YBMUwQfjL-Fy/view

NOTE: Game might crash or freeze on older hard drives, I recommend to put Rocksmith 2014 on SSD to navigate around this issue.

This is the ending of Rocksmith 2014 Edition – Remastered How to Skip Intros guide. Hope it will help you. If there is wrong or you have suggestions, please let’s know and comment us. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have this game myself but you can try and locate the actual file that contains the intro movie and replace it with an empty file. I find this trick works for most games, usually the file is called intro.bik or something similar.
Good Luck!